# How to delete files in Git remote repo

Tags: git, version-control, github

Say I have the following structure in Github (remote)

```
/project
          /dir1
          /dir2
          file1
          file2
```

Now, I forked the repo and change it to the following:

```
/project
           /dir_list
           /files_list
```

When ever I push the repo, I want the remote to be like:

```
/project
           /dir_list
           /files_list
```

and **not** :

```
/project
          /dir1
          /dir2
          file1
          file2
          /dir_list
          /files_list
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
git rm -r dir1 dir2 file1 file2
git add ./*
```

And commit and push only then.

Alterntively, if you paid enough attention and waited for an answer before actually doing any work with the repo: you can first delete everything, then do your work, then add everything back:

```
git rm -r ./* # this will delete ALL FILES
# ... copy the files you need, make changes
git add ./*
```

Comment: say, If I got 50 such files in the repo. I simply can't put every file in command line!!

Comment: @DennisRitchie it is, really. Sorry for that. But you have to do it once only. See edit, btw.

Answer (score 2):

Slight variation on [H2C03](https://stackoverflow.com/users/529758/h2co3)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12524463/6309) (upvoted):

If you have already done a lot of work, and don't want to enter each and every file to the `git rm` command... clone your GitHub repo again!

In that new clone, delete everything, commit and push.

Go back to your first clone (where you did a massive refactoring and already `git commit` that refactoring): `git pull --rebase`, then `git push`.
That would replay your modifications on top of the commit you get back from the GitHub repo (ie the commit registering the deletion of all the previous files).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`git mv`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-mv.html) command :

```
$ mkdir dir_list files_list
$ git mv dir1 dir2 dir_list/
$ git mv file1 file2 files_list/
$ git commit
```